# Why is xCode asking for Android Studio Gradle files?

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, gradle, plugins

I had to delete Android Studio off my MacBook Air to free up space for an xCode update. Now xCode is complaining its missing Android Studio files that have nothing to do with it but are somehow titled

[image: xCode Error displayed]

`file:///Users/administrator/Documents/Retrographic/Sprocket/Android/Gradle%20Binaries/gradle-2.2.1/lib/plugins/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar: warning: Missing file: /Users/administrator/Documents/Retrographic/Sprocket/Android/Gradle Binaries/gradle-2.2.1/lib/plugins/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar is missing from working copy`

What the heck is this and how do I fix it? I tried re-downloading the branch in SourceTree and pointing xCode at it but its still having the same problem. Do I need to just nuke and re-install xCode?

:(

Comment: is this some kind of cross platform project? this seems really weird

Comment: No. I just had both Android Studio and xCode installed on a system with full HD so I deleted Android Studio. This was the result...

Answer (score 5):

This seems very unusual...

My best guess would be to go through your various build settings in your project targets and ensure that this file isn't listed under anything for linking, building, etc.

If it is, delete it, provided you don't need it for your XCode project.

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs as that file was under your version control system such as git and now it is removed. xcode checks the status of git and complains if a file was removed. You can go to your version control system and commit this change so that xcode doesn't complain. If you are using git, you can do the following:

- git status
  --> This should tell the file was removed
- git commit ...

Comment: Actually, that does make a lot of sense. it says "from working copy". Good find.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible solutions.

## Solution 1

- Open your xcodeproj/project.pbxproj in a text editor
- Search for "xbean".
- Remove that line.

## Solution 2

If you are using an xcworkspace, there may be some other project that is including that file. In that case, I'd do that for all project files. If that is infeasible, do a grep `grep -r xbean .` and then edit the named files. This command will recursively search for all files mentioning this particular file.

Comment: tried searching xcodeproj/project.pbxproj in a text editor for "xbean" but did not find anything

I did find 3 instances of xbean in project.xcworkspace/userdata/administrator.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate:

Ø∞&††Ä'Uxbean“ AND 

ˇYNS.stringÄRUxbean“45_NSMutableString£8XNSString” AND

Z[†Än“45]^UNSSet¢]8]xbean-reflect“ CAN I just delete all 3 rows or the file safetly?

Comment: Nope. That apparently gets it to start complaining that Carthage libraries are missing: AlamoFire, Material, and SwiftyJSON.framework :(

Comment: Perhaps your build settings have an absolute path for some setting.

Comment: I think "manishg"'s solution is better. It does say 'from working copy' which can only refer to the git repo. Make sure the git-repo is fine. You can try 'git archieve' to make a copy of the current repo and opening that in xCode to confirm that it was indeed git's problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why is this happening, but i think there might be some file references in your project which are no more existing.
You can try this:
Search and delete missing files.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tried searching like this in xCode 8.2.1 = didn't find anything with "xbean" in it.